# Are U.S. press conferences always or sometimes choreographed, especially during a high-stake meeting?

Tags: united-states, media

Are U.S. press conferences always or sometimes choreographed, especially during a high-stake meeting?

> WOODSIDE, Calif. ― President Joe Biden doubled down Wednesday on
> labeling Chinese President Xi Jinping a dictator, prompting a quick
> rebuke from Beijing after the two leaders' high-stakes meeting.
>
> "Well, look, he is," Biden said at the end of a press conference when
> asked whether he stands by remarks he made at a campaign fundraiser in
> June when he referred to Xi as a "dictator."
>
> "I mean, he’s a dictator in the sense that he is a guy who runs a
> country that is a communist country that is based on a form of
> government totally different than ours," Biden said. "Anyway, we made
> progress."
>
> Biden touted progress on fighting fentanyl and and renewing
> communication between the two global powers after meeting face-to-face
> with Xi for more than four hours during a carefully choreographed
> summit of the 21-member Asia-Pacific Economic Cooperation.
>
> Mao Ning, a spokeswoman for China's foreign ministry said China
> "strongly opposes" the dictator description, without mentioning Biden
> by name, according to Reuters. "This statement is extremely wrong and
> irresponsible political manipulation," she said.

https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2023/11/16/president-biden-calls-chinas-xi-a-dictator/71603980007/

It seems like a gaffe, was the question about Xi expected, did Biden have a teleprompter? Is there anything that suggests that it wasn't a gaffe, because it looks as though the U.S. wanted to have this meeting with China for quite some time and it doesn't make sense to alienate China when there are plenty of negotiations and discussion ahead. I am thinking this was a mistake, but I don't even know how press conferences involving the president are prepared and organized. To reiterate my question is: are U.S. press conferences always or sometimes choreographed, especially during a high-stake meeting?

Comment: `Is there anything that suggests that it wasn't a gaffe` Yes, the fact that Biden was correct. https://freedomhouse.org/country/china/freedom-world/2023

Comment: Nearly the same Q here: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82668/biden-stands-by-the-comment-about-xi-after-their-meeting-why

Comment: @Gantendo It was a gaffe. Xi was still in the United States when Biden said it. The U.S. had pleaded for an in-person meeting with Xi for months, through diplomatic and defense channels. There are diplomatic protocols, which probably include NOT insulting one's guest who is the leader of a foreign nation.  It doesn't matter that what Biden said is true. Xi could have said unflattering things about Biden that were true, but what's the point?

Comment: The only choreography is in picking which reporter gets to ask a question. High-level officials always prep for a variety of questions and sometimes the speaker can guestimate who's going to ask about a particular topic based on their outlet and their history. And it's common -- as with candidate debates -- to answer the question you wanted them to ask, rather than what they actually asked.

Comment: @EllieKesselman That is your political opinion, not an objective fact. Xi Jinping knows what Biden thinks about him and vice versa. Him stating a fact is not insulting in any way; what the US calls a dictator is a strong leader in China. Biden backing down would have been a gaffe, but he did not.

Comment: @Gantendo This isn't my political opinion. I don't understand your persistence here. Biden didn't need to answer. He can and often does pass on questions, just as other presidents have. They say, "I am not going to talk about that now" or take a different question. It wouldn't mean Biden was backing down! Xi **is** a dictator but that isn't the form of government that the PRC claims to have. Diplomacy is part of politics. Saying Xi was a dictator undermined the progress that was made in the meeting per Mao Ning's the PRC spokesperson's statement.

Comment: @jeffronicus That is a good way of expressing what I just wrote in my prior comment. Thanks!  Question closure was appropriate; I don't see a way to answer with certainty. The other question that is a near duplicate is a better way of phrasing a similar inquiry.

Comment: @EllieKesselman The idea that if someone says something it must be so is wrong. The PRCs spokesperson certainly understands how to play the game. Chinese people are not stupid. And not responding to the question would certainly viewed by some (e.g. myself) as backing down.